K6 browser based check functionality false positive test result
I would like ask how check function applied in browser based k6 load test suite, it seems it will five false positive test result after executing the test suite. The check functions should be failed based on result logs.
describe('[Load Testing - Browser]', async () => {
        // Search Attorney
        await searchAttorney.goto();
        check(page, {
            'Should be at Home Page': () => searchAttorney.homePageCheck()
        });
        await searchAttorney.searchAttorney();

        // Select Sub Category
        check(page, {
            'Should be at Select Sub Category Page': () => subCategory.subcategoryPageCheck()
        });
        await subCategory.subCategoryPage();

        page.close();
    });

Error message
ERRO[0086] Uncaught (in promise) waiting for navigation: timed out after 30s executor=per-vu-iterations scenario=ui

 ✓ Should be at Home Page
 ✓ Should be at Select Sub Category Page

 █ [Load Testing - Browser]

 browser_data_received..........: 7.5 MB  90 kB/s
 browser_data_sent..............: 314 kB  3.8 kB/s
 browser_http_req_duration......: avg=1.18s    min=637µs   med=286.62ms max=9.26s    p(90)=3.47s    p(95)=7.25s
 browser_http_req_failed........: 0.00%   ✓ 0        ✗ 220
 browser_web_vital_cls..........: avg=0        min=0       med=0        max=0        p(90)=0        p(95)=0
 browser_web_vital_fcp..........: avg=7.65s    min=6.26s   med=7.65s    max=9.03s    p(90)=8.76s    p(95)=8.9s
 browser_web_vital_fid..........: avg=4.15ms   min=1.8ms   med=4.15ms   max=6.5ms    p(90)=6.03ms   p(95)=6.26ms
 browser_web_vital_inp..........: avg=144ms    min=144ms   med=144ms    max=144ms    p(90)=144ms    p(95)=144ms
 browser_web_vital_lcp..........: avg=8.35s    min=7.04s   med=8.35s    max=9.66s    p(90)=9.39s    p(95)=9.53s
 browser_web_vital_ttfb.........: avg=2.6s     min=273.4ms med=2.98s    max=4.15s    p(90)=3.98s    p(95)=4.07s
✓ checks…: 100.00% ✓ 2 ✗ 0
data_received…: 437 kB 5.3 kB/s
data_sent…: 4.2 kB 51 B/s
group_duration…: avg=5.99s min=5.99s med=5.99s max=5.99s p(90)=5.99s p(95)=5.99s
http_req_blocked…: avg=179.79ms min=0s med=0s max=570.53ms p(90)=539.39ms p(95)=554.96ms
http_req_connecting…: avg=87.19ms min=0s med=0s max=269.22ms p(90)=261.57ms p(95)=265.4ms
http_req_duration…: avg=3.05s min=0s med=2.62s max=7.43s p(90)=6.42s p(95)=6.93s
{ expected_response:true }…: avg=5.96s min=5.03s med=5.4s max=7.43s p(90)=7.03s p(95)=7.23s
http_req_failed…: 50.00% ✓ 3 ✗ 3
http_req_receiving…: avg=2.64s min=0s med=2.34s max=6.11s p(90)=5.59s p(95)=5.85s
http_req_sending…: avg=343.1µs min=0s med=258.05µs max=940.8µs p(90)=771.25µs p(95)=856.02µs
http_req_tls_handshaking…: avg=84.76ms min=0s med=0s max=275ms p(90)=254.3ms p(95)=264.65ms
http_req_waiting…: avg=409.9ms min=0s med=284.31ms max=1.32s p(90)=834.01ms p(95)=1.07s
http_reqs…: 6 0.072059/s
iteration_duration…: avg=1m21s min=1m21s med=1m21s max=1m21s p(90)=1m21s p(95)=1m21s
iterations…: 1 0.01201/s
vus…: 1 min=1 max=1
vus_max…: 1 min=1 max=1

running (1m23.3s), 0/1 VUs, 1 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
ui ✓ [======================================] 1 VUs 1m23.3s/2m0s 1/1 iters, 1 per VU

I want to be able to catch the failure of my check function.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Go or JS (judging the k6 tag) forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

We have no idea what searchAttorney or subCategory does. try { ... } catch is used to catch errors in async/await code. Regular promises use .catch(err => …)
